# Cannot bind argument in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have csv file that look like this but I'm not sure why I'm getting "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Case' because it is an empty string."

..............................................................................j...................................................

```
GIN, GID, UPN, PrimarySmtpAddress, Exists
2939343, KLE3kC, KLE3kC@prod.na.com, joel.smith@pp.com, TRUE
```

```
function HoldUpdate {
    $importCSV = Import-Csv -Path $Global:downloadFile
    $caseFirst = ""
    $CurDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $newComm = $newComm + " |  Added Mailbox to hold, $CurDate"


    foreach ($usr in $importCSV) {
       
        $importCSV | Where-Object { $_.ShardExists -eq "TRUE" } | ForEach-Object {
     
            try { 
                $GID = $_.GID
                $caseFirst = $GID.Substring(0, 1)
                $SMTPAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress

                #Use the correct eDiscovery case based on GID
                $casename = switch ($caseFirst) {
                    "b" { "BZ OneDrive Lit Hold Users"; break }
                    "c" { "CZ OneDrive Lit Hold Users"; break }
                    "d" { "DZ OneDrive Lit Hold Users"; break }
                }
        
                #Check to see if Users is on Hold in eDisocery using GID
                $holdPolicy = Get-CaseHoldPolicy -identity $GID -ErrorAction Stop
        
                    
                #if the hold exist, compare their SMTP address to exchange Location
                if ($holdPolicy.ExchangeLocation -ne $_.PrimarySmtpAddress) {
                       
                    #if the hold doesn't exist, Add or Update the hold.
                    Set-CaseHoldPolicy -Identity $GID -AddExchangeLocation $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -Comment $newComm
                } 
                else {
         
                }
                   
            }
            catch {
                $GID + "HOLD Not Exist"
                "Add new hold"
                new-CaseHoldPolicy -Name $GID -Case $casename -ExchangeLocation $SMTPAddress -Comment $newComm
            }

            
        }
    }
}

HoldUpdate
```

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Case' because it is an empty string.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-CaseHoldPolicy], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,New-CaseHoldPolicy
    + PSComputerName        : nam04b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com
```

Comment: (`$_`) the pipeline represented object, inside a `catch{}` block, is reserved for the current error that gets tossed into it from your `try{}` block. So, you'd have to save the variable as a different name first in your `try{}` block, to be referenced in your `catch{}` block. The error is indicating that `$_.GID` is in fact *null* since there is no property with that name inside your exception.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala hi bro, thanks for the advice but can you please show me how?.

Comment: Sure: `try { $GID = $_.GID ..... } Catch { new-CaseHoldPolicy -Name $GID ...... }`. So now, you're referencing the actual value of the current iteration of your csv for property *GID*.  Same thing applies to your *SMTPAddress*. (`....`) *stands for your code continuation*.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I think it's working for the "Name" so thanks bro but can you please check my updated post again because now I get similiar error for "Case".

Comment: I try to put the switch statent inside my try block but still not working

Comment: your `switch` statement is evaluating a variable (`$caseFirst`) that has never been defined before, hence `$null`

Comment: What Santi said:)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon and AbrahamZinala,  can you guys please check one more time for me pls. not sure why it's still not working". :(

Comment: your problem is with this: `$caseFirst = $gid.Substring(0, 1)`, this is defined before the actual assignment of `$GID`. You assign an empty string at the top (`$GID = ""`), but that's all it is. Hence the error. Then you re-assign the value down in your 2nd `Try{}` block again with an actual value. So that's why you see that message. So put your `switch` statement in your second `try{}` block **after** your assignment to `$GID = $_.gid`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinla I have just try that and still not working. (updated post) not sure where I'm doing it wrong again. :(  can you please just format and post the answer down below for me pls?.

Comment: Your code seems fine. The only issue I see is with your CSV and your `switch` statement conditions. In your CSV, you show the property of *GID* have a value of `KLE3kC`, then you assign your first letter to `$caseFirst` (`$caseFirst = $GID.Substring(0, 1)`). The issue is that you now have a `K` as the value with no condition in your `switch` that meets that; you only have `"a","b","c"`. So the result of `$casename` is `$null`, because you don't have a `default` to set to incase nothing is matched.

Comment: oh, sorry that I forgot to mention this,  in my actual code I have a to z but I just include a to c because I thought it'll be too long for StackOverflow post. I just ran again with real data but still giving me "Case" error.

Comment: Hmm, odd then. Maybe try quoting it since you have spaces in your name: `new-CaseHoldPolicy -Name "$GID" -Case "$casename"`? Other than that, your code looks good man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241556/discussion-between-abraham-zinala-and-ziico).

Comment: `$importCSV | Where-Object { $_.ShardExists -eq "TRUE" }` will return no objects, because the CSV does not have a column named `ShardExists`